# GNU Automake - build dynamic libraries statically linked against its dependencies

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make, automake

By default, libtool creates two versions of library - static one and dynamic one and that's what I need. I also need that my library, no matter what type is it - static or dynamic, will be linked statically against certain dependencies (several .a archives - lib1.a, lib2.a and lib3.a). I tried `--whole-archive` option in `_LDFLAGS` like this:

```
mylib_la_LDFLAGS=...-Wl,--whole-archive, -llib1 -llib2 -llib3 --no-whole-archive ....
```

but after Makefile generation, these flags are moved at the end of command, thus no effect is taken:

```
...-llib1 -llib2 -lib3.... -Wl,--whole-archive, --no-whole-arvhive,...
```

I also tried to provide `--static` flag in `_LDADD` like this:

```
mylib_la_LDFLAGS=...--static -llib1 -llib2 -llib3 ....
```

and this flag is omitted when libtool creates dynamic library (static library is fine).

How one should achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
mylib_la_LIBADD=-llib1 -llib2 -llib3...
```

should work.  Linking DSOs to static libs may not work, depending on how objects in the static lib were built.